# I need help or an example to get relative error using intg on Scilab

Tags: function, scilab

I'm doing Fourier analysis in a project on Scilab and using `intg` function to get definite integrals, but I need to also get the absolute error and most importantly the relative error for every time I use the function.

Now, according to the [documentation for this function](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/intg.html), there's a way to get the relative and absolute error. But I tried to do it and I couldn't.

I will show you what I did as an example, this is a definite integral from 0 to 1 for y = x^2:

```
function y=f(x),y=x^2,endfunction
inte = intg(0,1,f);
```

So the result will be:

```
inte  =

    0.3333333
```

But now if I want to get the error using the documentation, this is what happens:

```
[inte, err] = intg(0,2,f[,ea [,er])/2
                       !--error 3 
Waiting for right parenthesis.
```

Any idea about how to apply the documentation? Or even an example would be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [documentation](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/intg.html), `ea` and `er` are absolute error required on the result (*having default value: 1.d-14*) and relative error required on the result (*having default value: 1.d-8*) respectively. Now I am unsure whether you really want to override these values or not and in case you want to, kindly declare `ea` and `er` first. Thanks!

Comment: What I want to do is to get not only the results of the integration but also an estimated error. I thought you can obtain that estimation when you declare the two variables [inte, err]. But seems it doesn't work like this.